# Kartograph map won't display

Tags: kartograph

I can't get Kartograph.js to display my .svg map. Here's what I've done:

1. I've successfully made a .svg map from a .shp using the most basic json file I could with kartograph.py, according to Kartograph's docs, doing the basic world.json -o world.svg. Here's the json:

   ```
   {
       "layers": [{
           "src": "ne_50m_admin_0_countries.shp",
           "simplify": 3
       }]
   }
   ```
2. I've set up a simple http host with python and directed chrome to the host, since I understand you can't do this locally.
3. I've written the code below. I don't get any errors, so I don't what I've done wrong. Could it be that I haven't put in any layers? I wanted to make as simple an example as possible for my first try.

   ```
   <div id="map"></div>

   <script>
       function loadMap() {
           var map = kartograph.map('#map');
           map.loadMap('world.svg', function() {

           });
       };
   </script>
   <script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
   <script src="kartograph.js-master/dist/kartograph.js"></script>
   <script src="raphael-master/raphael-min.js"></script>`
   ```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

You must add the layer of the svg file.

In this case: map.addLayer('layer_0');

All the code:

```
$(function() {      
    var map = kartograph.map('#map',800,600)        
    map.loadMap('world.svg', function() {       
        map.addLayer('layer_0');
    });     
});
```

To see the name of the layer i open the svg file with [Inkspace](http://www.inkscape.org), and then press Shift+Control+X.